# Options for the RESTFul approach for follow and unfollowing

Tags: web-development, python, rest, http

I'm looking at implementing a new RESTFul call where a **User** can **follow/unfollow** a **generic** 'thing' item, but I need to know the best or common approach below, 1 or 2?

1) A **GET** or **POST** on the following URL's:

```
user/{thing_to_follow_id)/follow
user/{thing_to_follow_id)/unfollow
```

**Or**

2) A **POST** containing `thing_to_follow_id`

```
POST
user/follow
```

A **DELETE** on

```
user/follow/{thing_to_follow_id}
```

The first seems the most restful, but it feels wrong to post an empty payload where the second allow me to do a GET and return all things a user is following.

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), `GET` calls should be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) - that is,

> the client does not request, and does
> not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of
> applying a safe method to a target resource

Furthermore, one of the principles of REST is that URIs point to *things* (nouns), rather than to *actions* (verbs). In your case, the user would have a collection of things that they follow. That might look more like:

```
add a new thing to the collection of things the user follows
POST /user/follows 
{
    thing
}

get all the things the user follows
GET /user/follows

stop following a thing
DELETE /user/follows/{id}
```

Another option would be to use a mapping resource, such as:

```
add a new thing to the collection of things the user follows
POST /user-follows
{
    user
    thing
 }

 get all the things the user follows
 GET /user-follows?userId={id}

 get all the users following a thing
 GET /user-follows?thingId={id}

 stop following a thing
 DELETE /user-follows/{id}
 DELETE /user-follows?thingId={id}&userId={id}
```

Comment: @svarog raises a good point. In some of these cases - those where you have all the information on the client - PUT would be superior to POST because of its idempotency guarantee.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! GET should always be safe and the fact a user is 'creating' a new object should not be done with a GET. But, what worries me is that I would also need to find out the 'follow ID' to unfollow an item or edit it. For example, if a user is following an 'Article' to unfollow it I would need to know they were first following it. I guess that's an easy problem to resolve tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the mapping between a user and a thing to follow as a unique resource in of itself, which can have two different states, either true or false depending on whether the user is following the thing in question.

So a way of doing this would be for the client to PUT a new state of that resource on the server, since the client should already know the location of the resource. Your URL schema could be something like

```
/users/<user_id>/things/<thing_id>
```

or something similar that conveys that this is a resource representing the state of mapping between user and thing.

A GET on this resource would tell you if User A is following Thing B

```
Request
  GET /users/<user_id>/things/<thing_id>

Response
  200 OK
  {following: true}
```

And the client can change that state by `PUT`ing a new state

```
Request
  PUT  /users/<user_id>/things/<thing_id>

  {following: false}

Response
  204 No Content
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are basically updating/creating some line in some table when a user decides to follow or unfollow an item, you shouldn't be using GET.

Rather user POST or PUT

```
POST or PUT:
user/{thing_to_follow_id)/follow

PUT:
user/{thing_to_follow_id)/unfollow
```

And unless you are actually deleting something (if someone else can later choose to follow that item) then don't use a DELETE.